# JCalendar - setting date correctly in Java using correct format

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, date

I am using the `JCalendar` from here: http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/
I have used the JDateChooser to set date in a form and import into `SqLite` in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. WhenI try retrieving the date in the same format `yyyy-MM-dd` from the database with this code:

```
Date date = rs.getDate(10);
            fieldClose.setDate(date); //displays 01-Jan-1970 - I want (2013-01-08), one   that is similar in database.
```

I have looked at stackoverflow, and some similar posts exists, but fails to show recommendations in terms of format `yyyy-MM-dd` and consideration of `jCalender` and SQLite so i am having to post this. any ideas how to achieve a date similar to database, in the same format it was inserted and of same type.

I have just tried this:

```
String date =rs.getString(10); 
                ((JTextField)fieldClose.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(date);
```

returns:

2013-05-22 // comes in red line, meaning jDatechooser doesnt recognise it

Comment: there are two ways have to set SimpleDateFormat or setLocale, both are implemented in this Java Swing JCalendar

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat, try this example

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   Date date=null;
   try{
        date=sdf.parse(rs.getString(10));
   } catch (ParseException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   fieldClose.setDate(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. either you can use SimpleDateFormat in java
2. or use DATE_FORMAT('ColumnName', "Date Pattern") in Mysql SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format. Let me help you with the code

```
Date o = jDateChooser1.getDate();   //Import java.util not java.sql
String x = String.format("%1$ty-%1$tm-%1$td",o);
```